# How to add alternate Row color for DevExpress.UI.Xaml.Grid Gridcontrol?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, devexpress

I am trying to add alternate row colors for odd and even rows for devexpress xaml grid in windows 8 Metro App. How can I accomplish this? I am googling a lot but in most of my samples I am getting namespace reference mismatched. I am using Devexpress v12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `GridControl.ItemTemplate` (row template). This approach is demonstrated in Conditional Formatting demo module (DevExpress v12.2 feature demos):

```
<UserControl 
    ...
    xmlns:Grid="using:DevExpress.UI.Xaml.Grid">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:RowHandleToBackgroundConverter x:Key="RowHandleToBackgroundConverter" EvenRowBackground="Transparent" OddRowBackground="#FFDFE7EF"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
...
<Grid:GridControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Background="{Binding Path=RowControl.RowHandle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource RowHandleToBackgroundConverter}}">
            <Grid:GridCellPanel x:Name="PART_RowPanel" RowControl="{Binding Path=RowControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Margin="0,0,1,0"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid:GridControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The 'RowHandleToBackgroundConverter' class is implemented as follows:

```
public class RowHandleToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter {
    public Brush EvenRowBackground { get; set; }
    public Brush OddRowBackground { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
        if(((int)value % 2) == 0)
            return OddRowBackground;
        else
            return EvenRowBackground;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing... I dint even know that the coding was there... Thank you very Much..

Answer (score 0):

Thus?:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=EvenRow}" Value="False"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectionState}" Value="None"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource evenRowBrush}" />
</MultiDataTrigger>

<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=EvenRow}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectionState}" Value="None"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource oddRowBrush}" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Hi I am just the beginner for this environment. In which namespace can I find MultiDataTrigger? Do I want to add any .dll in reference? pls can u give it briefly?